# react-draft-wysiwyg toolbar not working when click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

when i press normal, image, link, etc it doesnt have the dropdown, what is wrong?

[image]

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertToRaw, convertFromHTML } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
// import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';

class DraftEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.defaultValue)
    if (this.props.defaultValue) {
      this.setState({
        editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
          ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
            convertFromHTML(this.props.defaultValue)
          )
        )
      })
    }
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    const html = draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    this.setState({ editorState: editorState }, () => {
      this.props.onEditorStateChange(html)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          // wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
          // editorClassName="demo-editor"
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
          onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        />
        {/* <textarea
          disabled
          value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
        /> */}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default DraftEditor
```